# How to fill error date value with 0 in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
id  date_original   
1    20200305     
2    2020305       
3    2020035
4    202035
```

How can I convert the 'date_original' column into 'date' column in pandas dataframe?

```
id     date
1     20200305
2     20200305
3     20200305
4     20200305
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me working well all formats if used `format` for match `YYYYMMDD`, tested in pandas 1.1.3:

```
df['date_original'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_original'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
print (df)
   id date_original
0   1    2020-03-05
1   2    2020-03-05
2   3    2020-03-05
3   4    2020-03-05
```